# Property not able to set

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got an issue with a list property that holds bookmarks. Before I started fiddling around it worked just fine. 
I want the list to always be sorted from a-z when fetched and I want the list to be able to set to the value put in.

I am not sure why it won't work. Any suggestions on getting the latter to work, or any suggestions to sort the list in any other manner is greatly appreciated and welcome!

Here the bookmark list is being set from a database query:

```
model.Bookmarks = GetBookmarks().Select(b => new UIBookmark(b, DbHelper)).ToList();
```

This worked:

```
public List<UIBookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
```

This doesn't:

```
public List<UIBookmark> Bookmarks { get { return Bookmarks.OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList(); } set { Bookmarks = value; } }
```

Comment: Your Bookmarks property references itself in the getter, and the setter

Comment: The `set` method will be an infinite loop

Comment: Looks like your version is recursive - Bookmarks uses the Bookmarks property - you'll get a StackOverflowException.

Comment: i.e. add a private backing field and reference that from your Bookmarks Property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using auto-properties, you **HAVE TO** use a field to store your data.

```
private List<UIBookmark> _bookmarks;
public List<UIBookmark> Bookmarks { get { return _bookmarks.OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList(); } set { _bookmarks = value; } }
```

*Basicly, auto-properties do the same thing, you just don't have to write anything.*

Comment: Ahh yes, what people say here makes complete sense. I feel like a buffoon for not noticing. I would perfer to use the auto-properties, but I couldnt figure out how to auto sort these. Do you happen to know?

Comment: Unfortunately, you either use an auto-property, and don't do any cool stuff with it, or have to implement everything about it. There is no half-way.

Comment: Properties are basicly glorified get and set methods, like what you would use in Java, or C++

Comment: Allright, That's a clear answer. I'll do it with the field and all the fancy sorting and such! Thanks alot for the insanely fast response.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a backing field instead of referencing the property itself in the getter and setter, like so:

```
private List<UIBookmark> _bookmarks;
public List<UIBookmark> Bookmarks { get { return _bookmarks.OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList(); } set { _bookmarks = value; } }
```

MSDN has some good articles introducing the concepts of [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) and [Auto-Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) that I would suggest reading up on too.